# IntelliJ IDEA create Unit Test shortcut/intention?

Tags: unit-testing, intellij-idea

I'm following the official documentation for using the shortcut/intention to create a Unit Test for a Java class (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/creating-tests.html)...

But step 2. "Place the cursor within the line containing the class declaration." does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Put the cursor on the name of the method you want to generate a test for, and click: ctrl+shift+T if you're on mac hit: command+shift+T

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this out, but I wanted to post it here as that IntelliJ documentation for step 2. isn't quite right, and it has no commenting feature:

*Place the cursor on the class name*; its not sufficient just to place it somewhere on the line as those directions say.

Comment: Instead of posting it here ping IntelliJ help and ask them to correct the documentation

Comment: That's not a terrible idea, but you never know how long it will take them to update it, if ever... so that's why I question/answered this.  Answering your own question on Stack Overflow is encouraged :  http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Comment: Finding where to give Jetbrains feedback is very difficult.  I ended up just filing a bug:  https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-167510